# Kernel Data Inpage Error

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod, kernel

I started getting this "BSOD" error a few weeks ago, and I have no idea how to find out why... It happens at random times and events so I have no idea what's causing it. I did a google search a few days ago and found out that you can look into the *.dmp file that is created during the error but, I failed to open it with the program from Nirsoft and, I also have no idea what am I supposed to look for... Can someone give me a hand? It's driving me insane...

I have an ASUS X55A Laptop with 4GB and Intel Celeron B830 1.80GHz x64...

Comment: run this tool http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html and look for the SMART values of the HDD. Do you see any errors?

Comment: [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/2317/BCDp7M.png)

Comment: your HDD is damaged. Replace it (with a SSD) to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error message almost invariably indicates a disk read error. Check your event log for reports from the "Disk" source. The cure is, of course, to replace your drive (or whatever other hardware is causing the problem, but drives are the most likely to fail).

Comment: This is what I have... 
Log Name:      System
Source:        Ntfs
Date:          14-Aug-15 0:07:13
Event ID:      55
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      UnixAxwell
Description:
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume C:.

The exact nature of the corruption is unknown.  The file system structures need to be scanned online.
I checked the hard structure and it says there are no errors... :/

Comment: What's with that "Dirty Bit" thing? P.S. The Allview Device is working perfect, it's my phone acting as a modem, and the UNKNOWN I have no idea... [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img913/2110/TiUIDz.png)

Comment: The term "dirty bit" may refer to the bit on a volume that tells NTFS "the OS was shut down improperly, therefore file system metadata may not have been flushed to disk and may be in an internally inconsistent state". Or it may refer to the "dirty" bit, which we more politely call the "page modified" bit, in a page table entry. This is a purely normal aspect of virtual memory activity. chkdsk /r should reset the bit in the first case.