# Blue Screen on Windows 7 (KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR (Technical information: 0x0000007A))

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windows-error-reporting

I am getting the following BSOD on Windows 7, the computer is not even starting:

> KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR (Technical information: 0x0000007A)

I have tried *Safe Mode*, *System Restore* and *Windows Repair*, but none of them did work.

BSOD ScreenShot:

http://prntscr.com/ohsfy6

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Given the info here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7a--kernel-data-inpage-error and you have "0xC000009C, or STATUS_DEVICE_DATA_ERROR, typically indicates bad blocks (sectors) on the hard disk." Are you able to run a `chkdsk /R`

Comment: i have access to a cmd on the windows repair screen, i will give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel Data Inpage Error](https://superuser.com/questions/956797/kernel-data-inpage-error)

Comment: @HelpingHand worked like a charm man ty vm

Comment: @yuribsl - I've posted it as an answer to hopefully help others in the future.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot provided, I can see the bug check code is: **0x0000007A**.

A list of bug check codes can be found on this page: [Bug Check Code Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-code-reference2). In this case we have: [KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x7a--kernel-data-inpage-error).

I can also see from the screenshot the parameters of the bugcheck, the important one here being **0xC000009C**.  The documentation reveals this to mean:

> 0xC000009C, or STATUS_DEVICE_DATA_ERROR, typically indicates bad blocks (sectors) on the hard disk.

The first thing to try therefore would be to run [chkdsk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) againt the drive.  Running with **/r** will find physical disk errors in the file system and attempt to recover data from any affected disk sectors.

If you can therefore boot into a command prompt, run:

> **chkdsk /r**

This should hopefully help.

> **TIP**: Bug check codes and parameters sometimes point you in the right direction, but typically a dump file is required.  A mini-dump may be useful, depending on the issue but it may take a complete memory dump.